# Adding a Facet to a G4TessellatedSolid

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, boost-python, geant4

I am trying to add a facet to a G4TessellatedSolid from Python.

I have defined a Class MyG4TriangularFacet which extends G4TriangularFacet i.e the class definition is

```
 class MyG4TriangularFacet  :  public  G4TriangularFacet
```

and the relevant constructor is

```
 MyG4TriangularFacet(G4ThreeVector v0,
                     G4ThreeVector v1,
                     G4ThreeVector v2);
```

The python code that tries to use it looks like

```
 facet = MyG4TriangularFacet(v0g4,v1g4,v2g4)
```

And I try to add it to a G4TessellatedSolid with

```
 tessellate = G4TessellatedSolid()
 tessellate.AddFacet(facet)
```

But I get the following error

```
 tessellate.AddFacet(facet)

 <class 'Boost.Python.ArgumentError'>: Python argument types in
           G4TessellatedSolid.AddFacet(G4TessellatedSolid,MyG4TriangularFacet)           
 did not match C++ signature:
       AddFacet(G4TessellatedSolid {lvalue}, G4VFacet*)
```

Now I was under the impression that G4TriangularFacet implemented the Virtual function G4VFacet. Is this not the case?

Is the issue that AddFacet is expecting to pass a pointer to G4VFacet?
Not sure how one would go about achieving that in Python

Comment: Whoops, I think this is the same mistake/omission as my previous question. I need to define the inherited classes using <base>

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add  to class definition for class hierarchy